# Content disappearing with jquery ajax update in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, cross-browser, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that's wrapped in a div with id `content`:

```
<div id="content">
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/signup' %>
</div>
```

shared/_signup.html.erb contains:

```
<%= form_tag sign_me_up_path, :remote => true do %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

If the user submits the form and there's errors, I render create.js.erb which contains only:

```
$("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/signup') %>");
```

With internet explorer this simply removes all of the content in `#content`, but it works great in all other browsers. I'd appreciate any help / insight.

Comment: What happens if you do `$("#content").html('foo')`? Does 'foo' appear in `#content` or is the div still blank? Do you have JavaScript debugging tools installed in IE? Can you examine the response of the AJAX call? If so, `"<%= escape_javascript(...) %>"` should probably just be a string of html markup. What do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the same pattern- remote form submission, javascript response which renders a partial and populates the html of a div using Jquery (1.4.4).  I saw the same behavior in IE, but it turned out it was due to a typo in the HTML partial.

The other browsers were just nicer about handling an unclosed span tag.  I suspect you've got a similar issue- validate the rendered HTML of your partial.

Comment: I considered that as well, but he's rendering the same partial as what was rendered on initial page load. If IE can render it once, you'd think it could render it a second time. But I suppose it's worth checking.

Answer (score -1):

This may be what you're looking for:

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/problems-with-rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-using-jquery-live-in-ie/

Comment: I doubt that's his problem. This article deals with callbacks not firing after AJAX calls. He doesn't have any callbacks, as his controller is simply rendering a js.erb template...

Comment: @Samo, I figured it was worth it to give James some paths to explore to figure out why it's not working.  I did some searching for issues regarding IE and contents not rendering, and http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript , specifically the excerpt "Ps1: That uses html5 to make our forms and links remotes (:remote => true), so it's not gonna work in any version of INTERNET EXPLORER yet." lead me to believe that it may be worth exploring existing issues between remote links and IE.  Personally, I thought it was a useful answer.  =)